# How to populate values for multiple input field using Material UI Autocomplete and react hooks

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-hooks, material-ui

Q1. I have used Autocomplete materialui library wherein i have created input field field which is consuming an object but while consoling the value i am having undefined values.

Q2. How i get populated values for multiple input fields if iam selecting value for Item Name field, whereas rest of input field i.e mrp, sellprice etc will be populate from the object consuming the values for Item Name field.(attached the image)

[Form img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zfawl.png)

```
const initialFValues = {
  id: 0,
  itemName: "",
  mrp: "",
  buyPrice: "",
  sellPrice: "",
  qty: "",
  manufactureId: "",
  manufactureDate: new Date(),
  expiryDate: new Date(),

};

export default function ItemForm(props) {
  const { addOrEdit, recordForEdit, invoiceId } = props;

  const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
    let temp = { ...errors };
    if ("itemName" in fieldValues)
      temp.itemName = fieldValues.itemName ? "" : "This field is required.";
    if ("mrp" in fieldValues)
      temp.mrp = fieldValues.mrp.length > 1 ? "" : "Price is invalid.";
    if ("buyPrice" in fieldValues)
      temp.buyPrice =
        fieldValues.buyPrice.length > 1 ? "" : "Price is invalid.";
    if ("sellPrice" in fieldValues)
      temp.sellPrice =
        fieldValues.sellPrice.length > 1 ? "" : "Price is invalid.";
    if ("qty" in fieldValues)
      temp.qty = fieldValues.qty.length > 0 ? "" : "Qty is invalid.";
    if ("manufactureId" in fieldValues)
      temp.manufactureId =
        fieldValues.manufactureId.length !== 0 ? "" : "This field is required.";
    setErrors({
      ...temp,
    });

    if (fieldValues === values)
      return Object.values(temp).every((x) => x === "");
  };

  const {
    values,
    setValues,
    errors,
    setErrors,
    handleInputChange,
    resetForm,
  } = useForm(initialFValues, true, validate);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    //  console.log("InvoiceId: " + invoiceId);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validate()) {
      values.invoiceId = invoiceId;
      addOrEdit(values, resetForm);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (recordForEdit != null)
      setValues({
        ...recordForEdit,
      });
      values.itemName=itemName.name
  }, [recordForEdit, setValues]);
   

// consuming from useform
    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        })
        console.log(values.itemName)  // -> this value is undefined 
        if (validateOnChange)
            validate({ [name]: value })
    }
      
    

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Autocomplete
            id="itemName"
            name="itemName"
            error={errors.itemName}
            [enter image description here][1]value={values.itemName=itemName.name}    -> this value is undefined 
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            options={itemName}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
            style={{ width: 300 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField {...params} label="Item Name" variant="outlined" />
            )}
          />
          {/* <Controls.Input
            name="itemName"
            label="Item Name"
            value={values.itemName}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            error={errors.itemName}
          /> */}
          <Controls.Input
            name="mrp"
            label="MRP"
            value={values.mrp}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            error={errors.mrp}
          />
          <Controls.Input
            name="buyPrice"
            label="Buy Price"
            value={values.buyPrice}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            error={errors.buyPrice}
          />
          <Controls.Input
            name="sellPrice"
            label="Sell Price"
            value={values.sellPrice}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            error={errors.sellPrice}
          />
          <Controls.Input
            name="qty"
            label="Quantity"
            value={values.qty}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            error={errors.qty}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Controls.SelectCustom
            name="manufactureId"
            label="Manufacture Name"
            value={values.manufactureId}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            options={itemService.getItemCollection()}
            error={errors.manufactureId}
          />
          <Controls.DatePicker
            name="manufactureDate"
            label="Date of Manufacture"
            autoOk={false}
            value={values.manufactureDate}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
          <Controls.DatePicker
            name="expiryDate"
            label="Date of Expiry"
            value={values.expiryDate}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />

          <div>
            <Controls.Button type="submit" text="Submit" />
            <Controls.Button text="Reset" color="default" onClick={resetForm} />
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another "onChange" property, and do something like below:

```
let's say you did onChange={handleInputChangeForAutoComplete}

const handleInputChangeForAutoComplete = (e,v) => {
 if(v!==null)
        {
            var a =  itemName.filter(option => option.id===v.id);
            if(a.length!==0){
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    itemName: v,
                    mrp: a[0].mrp,
                    buyPrice: a[0].buyPrice,
                    sellPrice: a[0].sellPrice,
                    qty:a[0].qty
                })
        }
}
```